# Why does the compiler output single warnings in multiple lines?

Tags: java, gradle, tfsbuild, javac, compiler-warnings

We recently integrated our android projects in the TFS Build process workflow, by calling the gradle bat file and handling the process' output and error streams.

The problem is that warning messages generated for the projects are written with line breaks to the error stream, resulting in multiple TFS build warnings for a single compiler warning.

This is a sample from our build summary, showing two compiler warnings being reported as several tfs warnings:

[image: 2 compilation warnings being reported as several tfs warnings]

Is there a setting somewhere that I need to change to tell the compiler to generate the warnings as single line outputs? Perhaps some configuration in gradle itself?

I would REALLY like to avoid having to handle this in the workflow itself as it would add a significant complexity to such a trivial thing.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the source code for the gradle logger at:

https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/core/src/main/groovy/org/gradle/logging/internal/AbstractLineChoppingStyledTextOutput.java

the text is indeed chopped to a certain length for ease of read, and formatting characters are inserted in the logged text.

And you can clearly see this logger style being initialized in:

https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/core/src/main/groovy/org/gradle/BuildLogger.java

without much of option of configuration;

Based on this analysis, unfortunately I don't think you can influence the logging style by configuration. But it should be quite easy to remove the end-of-line formatting in the workflow by doing some simple string parsing before calling WriteBuildMessage, isn't it?

Comment: Damn... thanks a lot for finding that out. Yes, it not _that_ complicated, but it feels extremelly hacky still, that's why I'd love for a way to configure it. I think I'll have to go with that solution then.